# Can an assembly be executed or loaded within C#.NET COM component?

Tags: .net, com, appdomain

I have a COM(written in .NET) which needs to create a an AppDomain and load/execute .NET assemblies in it. So that I could unload that appDomain later along with all loaded dll's. While working OK in normal(e.g. WinForms) .NET app, I get security exceptions if this code runs from within COM context. Assuming that the COM assembly is strongly named and placed in GAC it has a fulltrust policy. Can anyone explain if this is possible, and if not - why?

Comment: What kind of security exception are you getting ? I have a .NET COM LocalServer application which works fine (I dont use the GAC though).

Comment: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. when I try to AppDomain.executeAssembly().
And I get FileIOPermission(or smth similar) Exception when I try to load one.

Comment: also I switched to GAC for the COM component 'cause when creating the object e.g. from c++ code I got the fileNotFound Exeption. When I placed COM assembly into GAC it worked OK. Then I got that Security exceptions so I signed the assemblies I used and tried putting them into GAC - didn't work-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. In order to have CAS let you do that you should include

```
[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute()]
```

attribute in the COM assembly and the loaded assemblies.
Also creating objects and executing assemblies would require to add a proper permission set to the new app domain like this:

```
 AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
 setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); 
 PermissionSet trustPermissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
 AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain( "descriptive name", null, setup, trustPermissionSet);
```

Then you may simply create object via `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap()` or `executeAssembly`.
There also is a workaround to this issue - to use `Activator`:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle objHandle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(_pluginStore[path], path, pluginClass);

if (objHandle != null)
{
    object unwrappedInstance = objHandle.Unwrap();
    result.Add(unwrappedInstance);
}
```

but after its execution code has no rights to do any "complicated stuff".

You can find out more [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a47a9031-7153-48a0-b27f-68b85ebc6d56?prof=required).